# Rails Time Zone Not Changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Tried the following:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pretoria'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pretoria'
```

Not getting any errors, but it is still showing as London Time not Pretoria which is +2 Hours.

Any idea why?

Comment: Try `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` instead. And see if its working ?

Comment: could you give more information as to where you have set the `time_zone` and where it is still showing as 'London'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try to set the timezone on each request? That way you can eventually let the user set their own timezone and each request can be relevant to their time zone setting.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :set_time_zone

  def set_time_zone
    if logged_in?
      Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone) { yield }
    else
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-zone-3D